# Sqoop command --hive-import failed

Tags: hive, sqoop

I try to import database from mysql to Hive with Hadoop with automatically create table and load data to hive with " --hive-import " command from Sqoop.

I use command below to execute import with sqoop

```
./sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/testhive --table temenan -m 1 --hive-import --username anwar -P
```

when i execute this command error happen like this

```
8/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.login(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation;
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop20Shims.getUGIForConf(Hadoop20Shims.java:448)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.setConf(HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.java:51)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthenticator(HiveUtils.java:222)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:241)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:463)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
11/08/11 23:02:49 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:186)
11/08/11 23:02:49 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 1
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:326)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:276)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:218)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:362)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:423)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:180)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:219)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:228)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:237)
```

what's wrong with my sqoop command ? or are there other configuration in sqoop or in hive ?

Help me please

Answer (score 2):

You have to add --hive-table parameter and mention the table in hive. The below command will automatically create a table in hive with name **temenan_hive**

```
./sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/testhive --table temenan -m 1  --username anwar -P --hive-import --hive-table temenan_hive
```

Answer (score 0):

I have downgrade CDH3.1 to CDH3.0 , then i change Hive metastore to static as below:

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/hadoop/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

then all works well :)

Thnks all

Answer (score 0):

You can try **create-hive-table** tool to populate a Hive metastore with the table definition based on the table present in HDFS.

[Follow the link for create-hive-table](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html)